# Cast byte array to struct with pointer in it

Tags: c

I'd like to cast a byte array to a structure, with 2 pointers in it but each time I set the pointers the original byte array gets changed. Normally I would do that with a flexible array at the end like `char name[]`. But since I have two dynamic sizes in one struct I cannot do it this way.

I also tried it with memory allocation (see commented code) but since the byte array contains already all I need I don'T think I need dynamic allocation.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct {
    uint8_t mac[6];
} __attribute__ ((packed)) mac_t;

typedef struct {
    char type;
    uint16_t interval;
    uint16_t window;
    uint8_t name_length;
    uint8_t macs_length;
    char* name;
    mac_t* macs;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) set_config_t;


int main() {
    const uint8_t byte[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 'T', 'e', 's', 't', '\0', 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF};
    
    printf("byte array before casting: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(byte); i++) {
        printf("0x%02x ", byte[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    set_config_t* data = (set_config_t*) byte;

    data->name = &byte[7];
    data->macs = &byte[12];
    
    //data->name = malloc(sizeof(data->name_length));
    //data->macs = malloc(sizeof(data->macs_length) * sizeof(mac_t));
    //memcpy(data->name, &byte[7], data->name_length);
    //memcpy(data->macs, &byte[12], data->macs_length * sizeof(mac_t));
    
    printf("byte array after casting: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(byte); i++) {
        printf("0x%02x ", byte[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    printf("Sizeof byte %d\n", sizeof(byte));
    printf("Sizeof set_scan_config_t %d\n", sizeof(set_config_t));
    
    printf("type: %d\n", data->type);
    printf("interval: %d\n", data->interval);
    printf("window: %d\n", data->window);
    printf("name_length: %d\n", data->name_length);
    printf("macs_length: %d\n", data->macs_length);
    printf("name: %s", data->name);

    return 0;
}
```

Output if I run the program:

```
byte array before casting: 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x05 0x01 0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x00 0xaa 0xbb 0xcc 0xdd 0xee 0xff 
byte array after casting:  0x01 0x02 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x05 0x01 0x47 0x20 0x61 0x95 0xfd 0x7f 0x00 0x00 0x4c 0x20 0x61

Sizeof byte 18
Sizeof set_scan_config_t 23
type: 1
interval: 2
window: 3
name_length: 5
macs_length: 1
name: G a��
```

Comment: This looks fishy. What output do you expect?

Comment: The data should point to the byte array. Like data->type to byte[0], data->interval to byte[1]... and then data->name to byte[7] (which is the 'T') I hoped I can achieve this without allocating the data structure.

Comment: `I'd like to cast a byte array` So what now? What you want to do is not possible and doesn't work the way you expect. You have to implement something else, a completely different way, for example parse the input, allocate memory, create a pointer, assign the pointer. The input data you presented in the source code does not store a pointer value, it stores the data. `What am I missing here?` How to answer that question? There doesn't seem to be anything missing.

Comment: `I don'T think I need dynamic allocation.` Yes, you don't. You can assign the pointer value to point into the input string to the `T` element, and assign the `mac_t` element to point to the element `0xAA`. This creates a dependency on lifetime of objects: the structure pointed to data depend on the lifetime of the input data. It depends on _you_ if that dependency is acceptable or not.

Comment: Do you really need all the data to be contiguous? If not, just define several variables: `const char name[] = "Test";` `const mac_t macs[] = { { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF }, };` `const set_config_t data = { 1, 2, 3, sizeof(name), sizeof(macs) / sizeof(macs[0]), name, macs};` You may need to add `const` qualifiers to the `name` and `macs` members of `set_config_t`: `const char* name;` `const mac_t* macs;`.

Comment: You are not casting an array (and you can't, as there is no way to express that in C). You are casting *a pointer* to the first `const uint8_t` of your array.  And you are not casting to a struct.  You are casting to a *pointer to struct*, which is not the same thing at all.  C does not define the effect of dereferencing the resulting pointer, but one plausible interpretation is that it attempts to access the bytes of your existing array as if they where the bytes of a struct. That is consistent with your observations of the resulting undefined behavior, but you cannot safely rely on that.

Answer (score 3):

You have assigned the **set_config_t** same starting address as the **byte** array, and having same starting address means that they are sharing the address space for their data. Hence change in one will be reflected in another. In your example if you only assign the **name** pointer and comment out the next assignment, you'll find that only 8 bytes are changed in your **byte** array corresponding the to size of **name** pointer which is 8 bytes for 64bit machines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct {
    uint8_t mac[6];
} __attribute__ ((packed)) mac_t;

typedef struct {
    char type;
    uint16_t interval;
    uint16_t window;
    uint8_t name_length;
    uint8_t macs_length;
    char* name;
    mac_t* macs;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) set_config_t;


int main() {
    const uint8_t byte[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 'T', 'e', 's', 't', '\0', 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF};
    
    printf("byte array before casting: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(byte); i++) {
        printf("0x%02x ", byte[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    set_config_t* data = (set_config_t*) byte;

    data->name = &byte[9];
    // data->macs = (mac_t* )&byte[12];
    
    //data->name = malloc(sizeof(data->name_length));
    //data->macs = malloc(sizeof(data->macs_length) * sizeof(mac_t));
    //memcpy(data->name, &byte[7], data->name_length);
    //memcpy(data->macs, &byte[12], data->macs_length * sizeof(mac_t));
    
    printf("byte array after casting: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(byte); i++) {
        printf("0x%02x ", byte[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    printf("Sizeof byte %d\n", sizeof(byte));
    printf("Sizeof set_scan_config_t %d\n", sizeof(set_config_t));
    
    printf("type: %d\n", data->type);
    printf("interval: %d\n", data->interval);
    printf("window: %d\n", data->window);
    printf("name_length: %d\n", data->name_length);
    printf("macs_length: %d\n", data->macs_length);
    // printf("name: %s", data->name);

    return 0;
```

[image]

You may also notice that the values that are altered are independent of the value assigned to it. The value starts getting altered from the **7th** index which is the offset of name pointer in the struct. Which shows that the values are getting altered due to same address space.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of problems here.

- Padding is there for a reason. Since you use struct packing, the various members of the struct will end up misaligned, which on some systems means you can't access them directly or that may result in a misaligned access.
- Unless this struct is supposed to represent a data protocol or the like, it has a naive ordering of members which leads to lots of needless padding. You'd place members that are likely aligned for the given CPU first, like the pointers, then things like the `uint16_t` with 2 byte alignment, then all the byte-sized members with no alignment last.
- The source array is an array of bytes and not necessarily aligned either. Perhaps the compiler was kind to allocated it aligned in regards of the normal CPU alignment (32 or 64 bits etc), but there are no guarantees and you shouldn't count on it.
- Regardless of alignment, `set_config_t* data = (set_config_t*) byte;` followed by de-referencing the struct through the struct pointer type is plain undefined behavior still; a so-called "strict aliasing violation". Meaning that anything can happen.
- "Casting away const" also invokes undefined behavior. Never do that. Either remove const from the byte array or make the new pointer const-qualified as well.

---

How to solve all of that?

If this is actually a data protocol, which doesn't look like the case, then don't use a struct at all. Use a byte stream and serialize/deserialize it to a struct, if you must use structs. For data protocols there's often network endianess to deal with too.

Otherwise, if this is not a data protocol, then get rid of the harmful struct packing. Then re-order the struct members in sensible ways to minimize padding.

It is normally not possible to access a byte array through another larger type. Common solutions involve copying to a new object, either using `memcpy`, or the mentioned serialization/deserialization routines to copy member by member.

Another thing you can do is to swap the struct for a union:

```
typedef union {

  struct
  {
    char type;
    uint16_t interval;
    uint16_t window;
    uint8_t name_length;
    uint8_t macs_length;
    char* name;
    mac_t* macs;
  };

  uint8_t raw_data [n];

} set_config_t;
```

Since the array now contains an `uint8_t` array member, you can do the original ugly cast on top of the byte array and utilize an exception to "strict aliasing". Specifically in C standard terms: "an lvalue access through an aggregate or union type that includes a type compatible with the effective type of the object among its members" (using terms fetched from C17 6.5 §7).

Comment: More UB in the original code is the modification of a const-qualified object through the use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type.

Comment: @IanAbbott True, I didn't think of that. I'll add it to the list.

Comment: Of course, modifying a const-qualified object through the use of an lvalue with const-qualified type would be a constraint violation (because the lvalue would not be modifiable), so making the new pointer const-qualified wouldn't really help.

Comment: @IanAbbott How so? It's fine as far as strict aliasing goes. "an aggregate or union type that includes..." "a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object" "...among its members". If the struct/union is `const` then all members become `const` as well.

Comment: I was still referring to problems in the original code. `const set_config_t* data = (const set_config_t*) byte;` `data->name = &byte[9];` would violate the constraints of the assignment operator, so the suggestion to "make the new pointer const-qualified as well" wouldn't really help.

Comment: @IanAbbott Ah yeah, obviously it shouldn't be const at all if they plan to write to the members.

Answer (score 2):

At least this problem:

**Pointer vs. string**

`'T', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'` is a *string*.

`char* name;` expect a *pointer*, not a string.

`set_config_t* data = (set_config_t*) byte;` does not assign `data` to point to sensible data.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some object programming with getters:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t mac[6];
} __attribute__ ((packed)) mac_t;

typedef struct {
    char type;
    uint16_t interval;
    uint16_t window;
    uint8_t name_length;
    uint8_t macs_length;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) set_config_t;


const set_config_t *data_get_config(const uint8_t *data, size_t datalen) {
    assert(sizeof(set_config_t) < datalen);
    return (set_config_t *)data;
}

const char *data_get_name(const uint8_t *data, size_t datalen) {
   const char *name = (const char *)(data + sizeof(set_config_t));
   assert(data + sizeof(set_config_t) + strlen(name) + 1 < datalen);
   return name;
}

const mac_t *data_get_mac(const uint8_t *data, size_t datalen) {
   const char *name = data_get_name(data, datalen)
   return (const mac_t *)(name + strlen(name) + 1);
}
```